# How to use an inheritance height in css?

Tags: css

I want to talk about inheritance in CSS. If the parent has the `height` attribute (`100%`), then every child which wants to inherit that height, it can be declared directly. I mean: no need to set sub-parent's height to 100%.

Like this:

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
}

.div_1 {
  height: 100%;
}

.div_2 {
  height: 100%;
}

.div_3 {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_1">
  <div class="div_2">
    <div class="div_3">foo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The root height is: `200px`. `body` is a parent tag, `.div_3` is a child tag. So, if I want to use the same height with `body` tag, I have to define the height of `.div_1` and `.div_2`.

If not, it should be:

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
}
/*
.div_1 {
  height: 100%;
}

.div_2 {
  height: 100%;
}
*/
.div_3 {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_1">
  <div class="div_2">
    <div class="div_3">foo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks okay if I have only 3 div tags, what's happen if I have a template like this:

```
<div class="div_1"> <!-- need an 'inherit' height -->
    <div class="this"> <!-- need an 'inherit' height -->
        <div class="is"> <!-- need an 'inherit' height -->
            <div class="a"> <!-- need an 'inherit' height -->
                <div class="lot"> <!-- need an 'inherit' height -->
                    <div class="of"> <!-- need an 'inherit' height -->
                        <div class="sub-parent"> <!-- need an 'inherit' height -->
                            <div class="div_2"> <!-- need an 'inherit' height -->
                                <div class="div_3">foo</div> <!-- height: 100% -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why do we need to do the same thing for every sub-parent? `height: 100%;` or `height: inherit;`?

It should be wasting time.

Comment: You could just create a class: `.height-100 { height: 100% }` and assign the class to any element that needs to be 100%

Comment: Because the default value for `height` is `auto`, not `100%` or `inherit`. `height: auto` determins the element's height by the size the children elements will take, which usually is not equal to the size of the outmost container. Dementic already mentioned a possible apporach to this.

Comment: @Dementic Many thanks! Nice solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want all its child elements to have `height: 100%`, you can use the universal CSS selector `*` for this.

```
.div_1, .div_1 * {
    height: 100%;
}
```

If you want to apply it to all child `div` elements, you can use:

```
.div_1, .div_1 div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Another nice solution.